# Horizontally slide one page over another

Tags: jquery, horizontal-scrolling

I'm trying to create a horizontally scrolling page that slides one page over another. I want the page on top to slide over the main page until it reaches the main content(marked with a cross) on the left of the page. Then I want the page on top to stop sliding horizontally, but instead scroll content within the page. Hope this description is clear. I have included an image below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you need to build all the "pages" on top of each other, so you can just scroll down if you have javscript disabled. Then have jquery find the height of the browser then place that `height` on each "page" and set each page to `overflow-y:scroll;` then set each "page" to "far off screen" or so to the right. Then simply call left animate to 0px;